# Textbox does not clear in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

txtName is the first control in the page. When the page loads initially, it is empty. If there is text in the textbox and the user clicks on Refresh, it is not clearing the text.
At debug, i can see the textbox being cleared, but on page it isnt!!!!.
This happens in Firefox. Works fine in IE.

I have tried , Keeping the textbox outside the updatepanel, enveloping another updatepanel for this textbox alone, Enabling the viewstate, and also removing the clientidmode property.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBack ControlID="txtName" EventName="TextChanged"/>
 </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged"
   EnableviewState="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
   </asp:TextBox>

   //Some other controls

 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void page_load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     txtName.Text="";
     UpdatePanel1.Update();
   }
}
```

Comment: Set property AutoComplete="off" for textbox and try.

Comment: Try putting the command `txtName.Text="";` out side the `IsPostBack()` block if your requirement is to clear the textbox on each request

Comment: Cant keept it outside

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void page_load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {

     UpdatePanel1.Update();
   }
txtName.Text="";
}
```

Try this way

Answer (score 0):

Please add `txtName.Text="";` outside if condition. Try like this.

```
protected void page_load()
{
  txtName.Text="";
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to set `autocomplete=off` on your textbox, which will work on FF.

If you do need autocompletion, you can wrap your code into a form. and reset it in the onLoad event

```
<form id="autoclearform">
  //your textboxes
</form>
```

Now either add `onload="autoclearForm.reset();"` to your body or do it via javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoclearForm.reset();
});
```